# File length is 0 when recreating file from URI, or original filepath [getExternalFilesDir(String type) vs getFilesDir()]

Tags: java, android, azure-blob-storage

A little bit of background first: this app takes a picture and uploads to an Azure blob storage.

The picture is stored in a file (internal storage) using `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();`

To upload, I need to call the uploadFromFile(..) function like so:
`CloudBlockBlob.uploadFromFile(String path);`

The Azure SDK's uploadFromFile function looks like this:

```
public void uploadFromFile(final String path) throws StorageException, IOException {
        uploadFromFile(path, null /* accessCondition */, null /* options */, null /* opContext */);
    }

public void uploadFromFile(final String path, final AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options,
            OperationContext opContext) throws StorageException, IOException {
        File file = new File(path);
        long fileLength = file.length();
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        this.upload(inputStream, fileLength, accessCondition, options, opContext);
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

The issue is on the line `long fileLength = file.length();` where the fileLength is 0.

I have tested this against using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` for the storage directory. This works.

I need to use the internal storage vs external storage since that is specifically required for this project.

EDIT: The Android [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) documentation mentions nothing about this behavior. I am assuming this might be something to do with using the app internal storage.

EDIT: Adding some code

I am sending a [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) mPhotoFile to my Camera intent. This will contain the photo. mPhotoFileUri contains the URI for this file. Following is the code to use the path from the file.

```
File file = new File(mPhotoFile.getPath()); // value -> /data/user/0/com.example.devpactapp/files/JPEG_20160209_234929_1936823724.jpg
boolean fileExists = file.exists();         // true
long fileLength = file.length();            // length 0
```

Following is the code to get the file from the URI.

```
File file = new File(mPhotoFileUri.getPath());  // value -> /data/user/0/com.example.devpactapp/files/JPEG_20160209_235534_-1059496729.jpg
boolean fileExists = file.exists();             // true
long fileLength = file.length();                // length 0
```

I have to pass the path of this file to the [uploadFromFile](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/#uploadFromFile) function.

Workaround mentioned in my 'answer'.

Comment: You are not calling `URI.getPath().` Why is it in your title?

Comment: @EJP Made the edit. I wasn't sure if the URI was the 'major' issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't have all the information, I'm gonna make the call that the file is missing from the path you've given.  The [javadoc for length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length()) specifically mentions this case will return 0.

So try checking exists() before you do anything with the file.

Comment: Sorry for not having mentioned it. The file does exists. I'm editing my initial post to include this.

Comment: Please see the edits I made to the post, as well as the answer I posted. It does seem to be an issue with using getFilesDIr() vs everything else. Would love to learn if you have some insight regarding that. I have read all the Android docs regarding Files, end-to-end. Haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

While using internal storage the file path is different. I think it is stored in /storage/emulated in latest devices. Check for your file path. and see if you are creating a file with the absolute path.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I tried recreating the file using the absolute path. File exists returns true. File length is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. This is the function I was using to get the file that was being passed to the Camera intent.

```
    // Create a File object for storing the photo
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();

    mPhotoFileExists = true;

    // check if access to external storage exists
    // if returned true, return the new file
    // if returned false, user could have been requested for access
    // so, need to check if permission is available now
    // if still not available, return null

    if(haveWritePermissions())
        return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    return null;
    }
```

I changed the storageDir from `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();` to `getApplicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);`

Docs: [getExternalFilesDir(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)

I passed `null` since I didn't want to put `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, which would allow the Media Scanner to find the image file.

I understand that this, in no way, is a 'fix'. Still looking for an answer as to why getFilesDir() is causing this issue.

EDIT: Very pressing reason as to why this is not a good solution - external storage may not always be available, and there would not be any workaround in that case. Also, any other app with permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` can write here. So, no security is enforced either.